# Find a solution for $x^2\equiv -2 \pmod{p}$, when $p$ is an odd prime factor of $a^2+2b^2$ but not a factor for $a$ or $b$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

**Question**: Prove that if for some $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$, an odd prime number $p\mid (a^2+2b^2)$, but $p \nmid a$ and $p\nmid b$, then there is a solution $x$ for the congruence $x^2\equiv -2 \pmod{p}$.

This is (a variant of) the problem $59$ of Section $2.1$ of *An Introduction to The Theory of Numbers* by Ivan Niven et al.

**My Attempt**: I tried to use Wilson's theorem and Fermat's little theorem to construct a square number which is congruent to $-2$ modulo $p$. But I failed. How may I use the fact that $p\mid (a^2+2b^2)$? Could anyone give me a hint, please?

Comment: I'm sure that Peter Taylor's answer is the intended solution. But, if you have  the law of quadratic reciprocity up to this point, then it is also easy to give a formula for $x$ using Wilson and Little Fermat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$p\mid (a^2+2b^2)$ is another way of writing $a^2+2b^2 \equiv 0 \pmod p$, or $$a^2 \equiv - 2b^2 \pmod p$$
Since $p$ is prime and doesn't divide $b$, $b$ has a multiplicative inverse $\bmod p$.